# How to include string text in a STUFF function (XML Path)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Code:

```
ISNULL(LTRIM(STUFF( (SELECT ', ' + PL.Pipe_Product
                            FROM Reporting.PipelineInformation PL
                            WHERE PL.Project_ID = TI.Project_ID 
                            FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')),'___________') AS Pipe_Product
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show example source data corresponding to your desired outputs?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach can be to add a ROW_NUMBER into the sub-query to decide whether a comma or and should be inserted. This should be faster since you don't have separate queries against the same `PipelineInformation` table both of which are correlated sub-queries.

```
DECLARE @PL TABLE (Pipe_Product VARCHAR(50), Project_ID INT)
INSERT @PL VALUES ('gas', 1),('oil', 1),('orange juice', 1), ('milk', 2), ('honey', 2)


SELECT
    TI.Project_ID,
    SUBSTRING((
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN RowNum = 1 THEN ' and ' ELSE ', ' END + T.Pipe_Product AS [text()]
        FROM (
            SELECT 
                Pipe_Product,
                Project_ID,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Pipe_Product DESC) AS RowNum
            FROM @PL
            WHERE Project_ID = TI.Project_ID
            ) T
        ORDER BY RowNum DESC
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 3, 4000) AS [Pipe_Product]
FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) AS TI (Project_ID)
```

The sample data above outputs:

```
Project_ID  Pipe_Product
----------- -----------------------------
1           gas, oil and orange juice
2           honey and milk
```

Comment: @Dave Please feel free to upvote an answer if it helped you and accept it if it solved your question. This helps others to know which answers may have helped with your question. It also increases your reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this edited result instead:

```
reverse(stuff(reverse(ISNULL(LTRIM(STUFF((
                    SELECT ', ' + PL.Pipe_Product
                    FROM Reporting.PipelineInformation PL
                    WHERE PL.Project_ID = TI.Project_ID
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, '')), '___________')), charindex(' ,', reverse(ISNULL(LTRIM(STUFF((
                    SELECT ', ' + PL.Pipe_Product
                    FROM Reporting.PipelineInformation PL
                    WHERE PL.Project_ID = TI.Project_ID
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                    ), 1, 1, '')), '___________'))), 2, ' dna '))
```

Comment: Or just cut & paste. Try it now

Comment: Well the outermost reverse() does that. reverse of a reverse is back to normal.